# Warning: direct base class inaccessible in derived due to ambiguity; is this serious?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, ambiguity

I don't understand what the ambiguity is here.  I did identify the line that causes the ambiguity and marked it.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Spell {
    protected:
        struct Exemplar {};
        Spell() = default;
        Spell (Exemplar, const std::string&);
};

class SpellFromScroll : virtual public Spell {
    private:
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, SpellFromScroll*> prototypesMap;
    public:
        static void insertInPrototypesMap (const std::string& tag, SpellFromScroll* spell) {
            prototypesMap.emplace (tag, spell);
        }
        template <typename T> static SpellFromScroll* createFromSpell (T*);
};
std::unordered_map<std::string, SpellFromScroll*> SpellFromScroll::prototypesMap;

class SpellWithTargets : virtual public Spell {};  // *** Note: virtual

class Sleep : public SpellWithTargets {
    private:
        static const Sleep prototype;
    public:
        static std::string spellName() {return "Sleep";}
    private:
        Sleep (Exemplar e) : Spell (e, spellName()) {}
};
const Sleep Sleep::prototype (Exemplar{});

template <typename T>
class ScrollSpell : /*virtual*/ public T, public SpellFromScroll {};

Spell::Spell (Exemplar, const std::string& spellName) {
    // Ambiguity warning!
    SpellFromScroll::insertInPrototypesMap (spellName, SpellFromScroll::createFromSpell(this));
}

template <typename T>
SpellFromScroll* SpellFromScroll::createFromSpell (T*) {
    return new ScrollSpell<T>;
}

int main() {}

/*
c:\ADandD>g++ -std=c++14 Ambiguity.cpp -o a.exe -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors
Ambiguity.cpp: In instantiation of 'class ScrollSpell<Spell>':
Ambiguity.cpp:32:13:   required from 'static SpellFromScroll* SpellFromScroll::createFromSpell(T*) [with T = Spell]'
Ambiguity.cpp:27:90:   required from here
Ambiguity.cpp:23:7: warning: direct base 'Spell' inaccessible in 'ScrollSpell<Spell>' due to ambiguity
 class ScrollSpell : public T, public SpellFromScroll {};
       ^
Ambiguity.cpp:23:7: warning: virtual base 'Spell' inaccessible in 'ScrollSpell<Spell>' due to ambiguity [-Wextra]

c:\ADandD>
*/
```

How serious is it, and what can go wrong later on as the program evolves?

**Update**:  A solution is found by letting T be a virtual base of `ScrollSpell<T>`.
But in my program T is always a derived class of Spell, and Spell is always a virtual base of T.  See the diagram below.

```
                  Spell
                  /   \
              v  /     \ v
                /       \
               /         \  
   SpellFromScroll      SpellWithTargets
          \                \
           \                \
            \               Sleep
             \               /
              \             / v
               \           / 
             ScrollSpell<Sleep>
```

In the above diagram, why does `Sleep` being a virtual base of `ScrollSpell<Sleep>` solve the problem?

Comment: Any warnings should be considered _serious_, and you should try to fix 'em up.

Comment: But I checked my virtual inheritance and I don't see where the ambiguity can be.  I shortened my code above even more to isolate the problem as much as possible, what that problem is.

Comment: the code you have posted doesnt compile for me, MSVC 2012

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Have you never encountered false positives, or plain stupid warnings? (I'm looking at you, MSVC..)

Comment: @dwcanillas  Okay!  So that means that we perhaps do have TRUE amibiguity, and GCC perhaps simply fluked out.  But where is the ambiguity then?

Comment: @dyp If they're false positives, and certainly can be identified as such, there are usually ways to fix the warning using a workaround.

Comment: You're class diagram is wrong.  The top `Sleep` should be `Spell` and the last class should be `ScrollSpell<Spell, Sleep>`.  But, even with the warning gone, having two paths to a base is a bad design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
class ScrollSpell : public T, public SpellFromScroll {};
```

Here, `T = Spell`, so the `ScrollSpell` class has the `Spell` class as a direct, non-virtual base class, and also as a virtual base class through `SpellFromScroll`. That is the ambiguity. Declaring the base class `T` as virtual might solve the problem.

Also I don't really understand the point behind the design, so that might introduce some completely new issues.

Comment: Ah!  Your suggestion worked!  Does that mean that I don't need to worry about the other answer regarding undefined behaviour?

Comment: A possible issue: `template <typename T> class ScrollSpell : public T, public SpellFromScroll { public: ScrollSpell() : T() {} };` will fail to compile due to this ambiguity. Similarly, any member functions of `Spell` cannot be called without ambiguity (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Peter B's answer, I've drawn the class diagram that results when T=Spell.  The compiler doesn't know which path to take to get to Scroll when ScrollSpell is instantiated.  But, it also shows that using virtual inheritance doesn't solve the ambiguity.  Both methods result is two paths to `Spell` which is ambiguous.

```
            ╔══════╗
            ║Spell ║
            ╚══════╝ 
            /      \
╔═══════════════╗   \
║SpellFromScroll║    \
╚═══════════════╝    /
             \      /
           ╔═══════════╗  T=Spell
           ║ScrollSpell║
           ╚═══════════╝
```

Comment: Ok, I will look into this and see if I can change the code to avoid this, and then see if the ambiguity is still there.

Comment: This is the class diagram after my suggested modifications. (Shouldn't the class on the top be `Spell`?) Before the modification there would be two instances of `Spell` on the diagram, which causes the ambiguity.

Comment: @jmstoker.  Yes you're diagram is very clear, and though the line `SpellFromScroll::insertInPrototypesMap (spellName, SpellFromScroll::createFromSpell(this));` indicates that T = Spell, in my actual program T is always a derived class of Spell with Spell as virtual base, which still leaves it confusing.  I will make `T` a virtual base of `ScrollSpell` since it removes the ambiguity, but I will update my question with an actual derived class of `Spell`.  Hopefully, someone can still verify the ambiguity then.

Comment: @Peter B Yes, it should be `Spell`, copy-paste typo.  Unless Spell is two different classes (i.e. different namespaces) the diagram is drawn as above.

Comment: I've updated my question with a diagram and a derived class of `Spell`.  Though it solves the problem, I still don't see why `Sleep` needs to be a virtual base of `ScrollSpell<Sleep>`.

Comment: See my comment on the question.